# Задать время сессии (сохранить цвет текста на определённое время)

Tags: php, сессия

Есть file.html

```
<form method="post" action="file.php">
<p>
<select size="5" name="color">
<label>Цвета</label>
<option value="red">Красный</option>
<option value="blue">Синий</option>
<option value="yellow">Жёлтый</option>
<option value="brown">Коричневый</option>
<option value="green">Зелёный</option>
</select>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Выбрать"></p>
</form>
```

И file.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

   if (!empty($_POST['color'])){

    $_SESSION['color'] = $_POST['color'];  
  }
}
$color = $_SESSION['color'];


?>
<div>
<font color="<?php echo $color?>">
Some text here.....
</font>
</div>
```

Как сделать чтобы цвет текста сохранялся только 1 минуту в браузере после сабмита цвета?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй cookie для этого. Сессия тут не нужна.

Comment: с куками я знаю как сделать: setcookie('color', $_POST['color'], time()+3600 );  А с сессиями никак нельзя так сделать?

Comment: Сессия работает до закрытия бразера (или как задано gc_maxliftetime) и время сессии глобально. (https://habrahabr.ru/post/28418/)

Comment: Можешь еще кеш использовать но это избыточность.

Comment: ну хорошо, а как тогда продливают время сессии например пользователя админки. User закрыл допустим браузер, потом через минуту вошёл снова на mysite/wp-admin и попал сразу в свою админку, не вводя заново логин и пароль. С помощью куков реализуют это?

Comment: Да, например, auth_key юзера (галка "запомнить меня" при логине) хранят в куках. И по auth_key можно восстановить данные и заново залогиниться, не вводя по новой логин и пароль. А сессия все равно умирает.

Comment: ок, понятно, спасибо!

Comment: А если всё выполняется на одной странице, то как сделать чтобы после выбора цвета и сабмита этого цвета, строка c выбранным цветом в списке <select></select> стала выделенной и сохранялась выделенной?

Comment: Добавляй в куки в обрабочике при нажатии на кнопку сабмит, а потом уже делай сабмит. Или вообще делай ajax отправку формы без перегрузки страницы. и в $.ajax({success: function...}) добавляй в куки

Comment: а вот я и не знаю как это делать для списка option selected value

Comment: не, давайте пока без аякса

Comment: Просто нужно выбранную строку цвета в списке после сабмита чтобы стала selected

Comment: разобрался. Нужно сделать <option value="red" <?php if ($_COOKIE['color']=='red') echo 'selected="selected"'?>>Красный</option> И так для каждого option

Answer (score 0):

```php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (!empty($_POST['color'])) {
    $_SESSION['post_color'] = array(
      'color' => $_POST['color'],
      'time' => time()
    );
  }
} else if (
  isset($_SESSION['post_color']) &&
  $_SESSION['post_color']['time'] + 60 > time()
)
  $color = $_SESSION['post_color']['color'];
else
  $color = $_SESSION['color'];
```

Comment: Это даже не костыль, это инвалидная коляска целая)))